# When does it make sense to use threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm having some trouble figuring out if it makes sense to use threads for the solution that I'm building or if I should just leave it as it is. I have a script (`manager.py`) that calls another script (`sniff.py`) to sniff network packets, and another (`parse.py`) to parse the sniffed packets.

The manager.py script is only used to trigger the application. For every packet received, the sniffer will handle it. This packet is then sent to the parser.

Does it make sense to use threads for the `sniff.py` and `parse.py` handled in the `manager.py`?

manager.py:

```
import sniff
...
def main():
    sniff.main()
```

sniff.py:

```
import parse
...
def main():
    packets = snifferFunction()
    parse.main(packets)
```

parse.py:

```
def main(pkts):
    parseFunction(pkts)
```

Answer (score 0):

A disadvantage of threads in some Python implementations (like CPython) is that due to the global interpreter lock ("GIL") only *one* thread at a time can be executing Python bytecode.

An option could be to use multiprocessing. The manager lauches both sniff and parser after setting up a Pipe or shared memory for them to communicate with. If you have a multi-core machine (and who doesn't, these days) this will use two cores. Since these are two different processes each running Python you won't be bothered by the GIL, but you have to share data between processes. That introduces some overhead. But in this scenario you could run several parsers behind one sniffer (assuming that parsing a packet takes longer than sniffing one). So this might scale better for lots of traffic.

Another option is to use event-driven programming. Your program runs a loop that checks for the availability of network packets. If so, it is read an put into a queue. If there is no network packet coming in and there are packets in the queue, the sniffer is run on the first packet in the queue. This assumes that the sniffer can run pretty quickly. If not, it has to be divided up into smaller subtasks. You can e.g. use a framework like Twisted for event-driven programming.

Comment: Or it might be a lot slower to use multiprocessing because of the IPC overhead. The GIL is released before a blocking system call, such as a read from a network interface.

Answer (score 0):

Description of the problem does not specify that you have to do net sniff in parallel, does it? If so, why not just make a package and import relevant classes in `manager.py`?

If you do need parallelism for reasons of performance, do not use threads, but smth like this:

http://www.gevent.org/

Or this:

https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/

Twisted might actually be preferable for this kind of work since it's essentially network-oriented concurrent library.